# How to watermark image in pdf exported in datatable

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables, watermark, export-to-pdf

I am using datatables to display data in table format and have given export option , to export data into csv , pdf . Now i want to add a watermark image into pdf that gets downloaded from button in data table.

Here is code i tried but it didnt work for me,

```
var table = $('#holiday').DataTable( {
                    "dom": '<"nav" B>lfrtip',
                    "buttons": [
                                'excelHtml5',
                                'csvHtml5',
                                {
                                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                    customize: function ( doc ) {
                                    doc.content.splice( 1, 0, {
                                          margin: [ 20, 20, 20, 20 ],
                                          alignment: 'center',
                                          image:'data:image/png;base64,abcdddd'
                                }]  });
```

I also tried using watermark in place of image , but i didnt get result. Please help me regarding this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you mean didnt get result ? You didn't get any result in this case please specify the error you got or image is not coming properly ?

Comment: There is no error , but the option 'watermark' for image is not working. Eg: watermark: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA' . Then when PDF button is clicked to export then nothing works. The data doesnt get downloaded as pdf also.

Answer (score 1):

I think they have added watermark option.

https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/pull/492

so this will work use pdfmake v0.1.27

```
customize: function ( doc ) {doc.watermark = {text: 'watermark text', color: 'blue', opacity: 0.1};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user3933674 as you want an watermark for your **pdf** which you get from exporting an Datatable.

I think its not possible yet as there is no mention of setting image(watermark) as background in document http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted of pdfmake.

For inserting image into PDF please find the below code.

```
 $('#example').DataTable( { 
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        customize: function ( doc ) {
            doc.content.splice( 0, 0, {
                margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
                alignment: 'center',
                image: 'based64 encoded image'
            } );
        }
    }                 
    ]
 } );
```

For your reference I am providing the demo of inserting custom image into pdf export of datatable.
https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/rbunuv9b/1/

Comment: Thanks so much Prakash. I have used the same code u have provided above. Adding image  successfully. But watermark feature i am unable to make up. I guess from dataTable its not possible. Any other way to export dataTable into pdf , csv , xls etc and add watermark image ?

Comment: I don't think its possible in  excel or csv.

Comment: Oh k then atleast for pdf is it possible ?